# ReactJS is not working

Tags: react.js

yarn start in reactJS is not working.
showing below things..
.

```
Error: watch /home/khiller/new-app/public ENOSPC
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1382:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/khiller/new-app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:38:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/khiller/new-app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/khiller/new-app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:233:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/khiller/new-app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:429:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/khiller/new-app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:477:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/khiller/new-app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:482:16)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: The following questions answered it already. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-what-is-enospc-error-and-how-to-solve/32600959#32600959

Comment: You can't get it to work, doesn't mean the technology is not working

Answer (score 0):

Listen uses inotify by default on Linux to monitor directories for changes. It's not uncommon to encounter a system limit on the number of files you can monitor. For example, Ubuntu Lucid's (64bit) inotify limit is set to 8192.

Run the below command to avoid ENOSPC:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

For Arch Linux add this line to /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

Then execute:

```
sysctl --system
```